# Shorter method for checking ComboBoxItem has been selected

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a large number of ComboBoxes in my application. They all need to start blank, so their default selected index is always set to -1 and the boxes are prepopulated with hardcoded choices. Some of the boxes aren't required to have an item selected when the form is submitted, so are allowed to remain blank (and stay at an index of -1).

Currently Im using the following to check if an item is selected, and assign its content value if it has.

```
if (ComboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    MyObject.Val1 = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.Items[ComboBox.SelectedIndex]).Content.ToString();
}
```

Obviously I can't simply use

```
((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.Items[ComboBox.SelectedIndex]).Content.ToString();
```

on its own in case no value has been selected as it will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Is there a more elegant way to do this, or am I stuck to running this qualifier every time I need to?

**Edit:**

I did have an idea using a function like so

```
public string ComboChecker(ComboBox box, int index)
{
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return ((ComboBoxItem)box.Items[box.SelectedIndex]).Content.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

That way I would only need to do `MyObject.Val = ComboCheck(ComboBox,ComboBox.SelectedIndex)` each time instead

Comment: You could write a reusable helper function - or use the ternary operator.

Comment: Bind the MyObject.val to the combobox selecteditem property

Comment: @MojoJojo and when no item is selected?

Comment: it will be null which you can handle

Comment: @MojoJojo checking for null would be no different to checking for a selected index of -1

Comment: You could have a default value to that property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void GetSelectedValue(ComboBox c, Action<String> gotValue) {
    if( c.SelectedIndex >= 0 ) {
        ComboBoxItem item = c.Items[ c.SelectedIndex ];
        gotValue( item.Content.ToString() );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GetSelectedValue( MyComboBox, v => MyObject.Val1 = v );
```

Comment: I like this, it's tidy and a single line